# /var/run/user/1000 owned by root

Tags: permissions, network-manager

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and having an intermittent problem where /var/run/user/1000 is getting the  wrong ownership. UID 1000 is my uid for a standard user, however for some reason the ownership of the above directory is being set to root.

This is causing a problem with nm-applet not permitting switching between different access points. When the above incorrect ownership occurs, attempts to switch the wifi AP results in the following error:

```
Failed to add/activate connection
(32) No session found for uid 1000 (unknown)
```

To correct this I have to `rm -rf /var/run/user/1000`, log out, and log back in.

If I can provide more data on my system that would help to debug this issue please let me know.

If anyone has any pointers that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have this issue too, do you find any solution instead of `chown` on this directory?